# Quel est le sens d'« investissement » dans ce contexte ?

Tags: sens, littérature, noms

Dans le livre *Littérature. Textes et documents. XIX  e siècle* de Dominique Rincé et Bernard Lecherbonnier j'ai lu cette phrase faisant référence  au réalisme comme mouvement littéraire (j'y ai ajouté les caractères en gras):

> Tout en laissant place à l'imagination et à l'**investissement** affectif personnel, le romancier réaliste professe l'objectivité.

J'ai cherché le terme « investissement » dans des dictionnaires ([1](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/investissement) et [2](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/investissement)), mais je n'en comprends pas le sens dans le contexte de l'extrait ci-dessus.  Quelqu'un pourrait-il m'expliquer ce que cela veut dire ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C'est le sens dans le troisième onglet de votre lien sur TLFi:

[image]

Le romancier réaliste professe l'objectivité, opposée à la subjectivité de l'imagination et d'un investissement affectif personnel. Il ne dénie pas la possibilité de s'investir affectivement, c'est-à-dire de charger (son oeuvre?) d'une signification personnelle et affective, tout en professant l'objectivité.

Comment: Oui, j'ai imaginé ceci : c'est pourquoi j'ai mis le lien vers cette signification de TFLI. Cependant, je ne peux pas comprendre le sens dans le contexte de la phrase citée.

Comment: @Charo J'ai mis à jour ma réponse. Est-ce que cela vous aide mieux?

Comment: Oui, @Frank, ça va mieux maintenant.

Comment: L'entrée du verbe "investir" peut aussi aider : https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/investir (4) `Mettre son énergie psychique dans`.